# Process map of objects from LWC in Apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, map, parameters

I'm creating new records in my LWC and have a map to allow for updating values before doing the save and I finally got the LWC to communicate with the controller, but the values sent seem to be empty, so I'm not sure where things are going wrong.
I tried with `jsonData:this.mapOfFields`
and with `answers:this.mapOfFields` but neither works.

JS:

```
import saveAnswers from "@salesforce/apex/QuestionnaireAnswerController.SaveAnswers";

@track mapOfFields = [];


this.mapOfFields.forEach(function (answ) {
  console.log("create answer answ" + JSON.stringify(answ));
});

console.log("create answer answ" + this.mapOfFields);

saveAnswers({
  jsonData: this.mapOfFields
}).then((result) => {
  console.log("Answers saved: " + result);
});
```

If debug the JS I can see the map has values and the call to the controller completes as per the returned boolean.

[image]

Yet when I view the debug log from the Apex, it says the passed value is empty. How should I pass and how should I receive, since this isn't working?

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static boolean SaveAnswers(List<Map<String, String>> answers) {
    System.debug(
      '####QuestionnaireAnswerController SaveAnswers ' + answers.size()
    );
    for (Map<string, String> answer : answers) {
      for (String qa : answer.keySet()) {
        System.debug(
          '####QuestionnaireAnswerController SaveAnswers answer: ' +
          answer.get(qa)
        );
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How is it all working for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the an equivalent datatype from `LWC` to `Apex`.

- From `LWC` you are passing an `Array` called `jsonData`
- Into `Apex` you are receiving a `Map<String,String>` called `answers`

Both the name and datatype need to match.

Either pass a map (javascript `Object`) - and call it `answers`

**OR**

Receive an Array from into `Apex` - and call keep the name `answers`

---

I'm going with option 2 because there is no good reason to be passing a `Map`.

Javascript:

```
//rename your variable, because it's an array, not a map
@track answersArray = []; 

saveAnswers({ answersJSON: JSON.stringify(this.answersArray)})
.then((result) => {});
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled //remove cacheable
public static boolean SaveAnswers(String answersJSON) {
  Answer[] answers = (Answer)JSON.deserialize(answersJSON,Answer[].class);
  for (Answer answer : answers){
    System.debug('####QuestionnaireAnswerController SaveAnswers answer: ' + answer.key + ' ' + answer.value);
  }
  return true;
}

public class Answer{
  public String key {get;set;}
  public Question_Answer__c value {get;set;}
}
```

---

OK... take two. This is probably the simplest approach:

You have an array with objects containing parameters `key` and `value`.
Extract the object named `value` into an array to send to Apex.

```
let answers = answersArray.map( answer=>answer.value);
saveAnswers({ answersJSON: JSON.stringify(answers)})
.then((result) => {});
```

Your Apex method becomes much simpler as we don't need a custom data type:

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static Boolean SaveAnswers(String answersJSON) {
  Question_Answer__c[] answers = (Question_Answer__c)JSON.deserialize(answersJSON,Question_Answer__c[].class);
  for (Question_Answer__c answer : answers){
    System.debug('####QuestionnaireAnswerController SaveAnswers answer: ' + answer.key + ' ' + answer.value);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I've changed the LWC call to 'answers: this.mapOfFields' , but am getting an 'uncaught' error in the js debug now. I don't quite know what to change where. How do I make the JS side an object, or what do I change on the apex side?

Comment: I'm getting this error after making the changes you suggested. It seems to think there's only one, not multiple records: 
"List<QuestionnaireAnswerController.Answer> answers
Illegal assignment from QuestionnaireAnswerController.Answer to List<QuestionnaireAnswerController.Answer> "

Comment: It was still not happy. I did some searching and found the line had to be as this: "Answer[] answers = (Answer[]) JSON.deserialize(answersJSON, Answer[].class);".  I thought yay! Except when I then tested I got an error "System.NullPointerException: null input to JSON parser".  I have a console.log right before the call to Apex and it definitely contains values, yet when it gets into the apex class it appears to be null.  I added a debug to display the passed string and this is what it shows: [119]|DEBUG|####QuestionnaireAnswerController SaveAnswers answersJSON: null

Comment: In my JS I added: "    console.log("JSON array: " + JSON.stringify(this.mapOfFields));
    saveAnswers({ answers: JSON.stringify(this.mapOfFields) }).then(          " and the js debug displays the content just before the call: "      JSON array: [{"key":"a28p0000000XifnAAC","value":{"RecordTypeId":"012p0000000G9mXAAS","Question_Number__c":2,"Related_Question__c":"a28p0000000XifnAAC","Requires_File_Upload__c":false}},{"key":"decl","value":{"RecordTypeId":"012p0000000G9mXAAS"

Comment: Ah, yes that makes a difference - I now get the data into my apex class, but am now getting this error there: "System.JSONException: Illegal value for primitive" on the deserialize line (Answer[] answers = (Answer[]) JSON.deserialize(answersJSON, Answer[].class);)

Comment: I found the problem! Instead of have 'string' as the type for 'value', I made it the actual object, and now it works perfectly! So   public class Answer {
    public String key { get; set; }
    public Question_Answer__c value { get; set; }
  }
 If you can update your answer I can tick it as the solution :)

Comment: Done. I never realised you were passing in an object there... I might have answered it a bit differently if I'd known, but hey, glad it's working :)

Comment: Is there a better way to do it with an object? My title actually says 'objects' :)

Comment: Yes, I thought you meant Javascript objects, not sObjects. New answer at bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145113/discussion-between-irene-and-caspar-harmer).

Comment: changed shorthand arrow syntax. look at answer now.